# javaFX - tableview getting selected items

Tags: database, sqlite, javafx, tableview, scenebuilder

How can I get a selected item in a row from tableview in javaFX with Sqlite Database.

I am now using this to get the Index of the row:

(...)

```
@FXML
    private ObservableList<UserData> data;

@FXML
    private TableView table;

@FXML
    private void pressTableAction() {
        System.out.println("Selected index: " +table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    }
```

(...)

```
 public void initialize (URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        try {
            con = DataBaseConnection.getConnected();
            stat = con.createStatement();
            data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person");
            while (rs.next()) {
                data.add(new UserData(rs.getInt("p_id"), rs.getString("Name")));
            }
            column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("p_id"));
            column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Name"));
            table.setItems(null);
            table.setItems(data);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
        }






Public static class UserData {

        private IntegerProperty p_id;
        private StringProperty Name;


        private UserData(Integer p_id, String Name) {
            this.p_id = new SimpleIntegerProperty (p_id);
            this.Name = new SimpleStringProperty(Name);

        }

        public IntegerProperty p_idProperty() {
            return p_id;
        }

        public StringProperty NameProperty() {
            return Name;
        }
}
```

My db looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person (p_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);
```

How can I get the p_id or the Name of the row I clicked?

```
@FXML
    private void pressTableAction() {
    System.out.println("Selected index: " + table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    System.out.println("Selected p_id: " + ????)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, do **not** use raw types for your table and table columns. Your IDE should be generating lots of warnings for this. So you should do

```
@FXML
TableView<UserData> table ;
```

instead of the declaration you have. Similarly the columns should be declared with the appropriate types.

If your model class `UserData` follows the standard [JavaFX properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107), it will have a `getP_id()` method, and you can do

```
UserData selected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
System.out.println("Selected p_id: "+selected.getP_id());
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you but it's not working:(

****In the first line i get the message= Incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to UserData.



***Second line(.getP_id) = cannot find symbol. Location:variable selected of type UserData




It's my first time working with Javafx/sqlite..so sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: See update. You need to fix your table declaration. I am assuming (from your cell value factory) that your `UserData` class has a `getP_id()` method.

Comment: Read the [tutorial I linked](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) in the answer. You should just have `get` and `set` methods corresponding to the property.

Comment: @James_D I want to get multiple selected items. So i used 'ObservableList<DailySalesTableData> productSelected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();' But, how to retrieve cell data from this observablelist? Can you please help me?

Comment: Oky, it  really was missing get/set method.
It is working now.
Thanks